# How to represent an arbitrary character without dot including new line?

Tags: python, regex

In a Python regex, I would like dot still not match `\n`, and also want to match any character (including `\n`) by some way. How can I match any character (including `\n`)?

E.g. I want to match the lines before the first line which is 1 to 8 characters long. So my regex is `^([\.\n]*)\n^.{1,8}$` with re.M, but it doesn't work. Thanks.

```
>>> p1='''Modellunabh                                                                                                      
... MUSiCMUSiC                                                                                                     
... PARALLEL'''
>>> p1
'Modellunabh\nMUSiCMUSiC\nPARALLEL'
>>> p=re.compile(r'''^([\.\n]*)$\n^(.{1,8})$''', re.M)
>>> m=re.search(p, p1)
>>> m
>>>
```

Comment: Is this a raw string?

Comment: what do you mean by raw string?

Comment: Is your string prefixed by an R?

Comment: no. ................

Comment: can you put some sample data and expected output?

Comment: Raw string: `r'blabla'`

Comment: You want a dot to not match `\n` but also match `\n`? That makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @Fede:  put it.   ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not fully sure if I understood your question, but will post this answer since might help you (i can delete it if not).

I think you want to do something like this:

```
([\s\S]*?)\.{1,8}
```

Comment: Thanks. itWorks, but why `[\.\n]` not works, while `[\s\S]` does?

Comment: @Tim well the \.\n you are select only the single character "." and the new line. But \s\S will match everything. Think of it as a union set .

Comment: @Tim no, the dot inside a character class works a literal character. Btw, did my answer solved your question?

Comment: The \.\n you are select only the single character ".", and the dot inside a character class works a literal character. So both `\.` and `.` inside `[]` mean the same as the literal dot?

Comment: @Tim yes, it's the same. You can check the explanation here https://regex101.com/r/yB6dY2/2

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to achieve the same thing in `[]` as `.` outside `[]`

Comment: @Tim nope, because you want two different behaviours for the same literal. The way to do it is the one I showed you.